# Как исправить ошибку Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' trace

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Суть проблемы в том, что я пытаюсь записать в таблицу данные где `u_id` равен данному из поста, но мне пишет такую ошибку:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' trace

Использую библиотеку RedBeanPHP.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once ('db.php');

    $data = $_POST;
    $user = R::dispense('users');
    $user->u_id = $data['u_id'];
    $user->u_money = $data['u_money'];
    R::store($user);
?>
```